# how to set margins for an EditText inside an AlertDialog

Tags: android

I use an `EditText` inside an `AlertDialog` like:

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
    alert.setView(input);
```

Now I'd like to set margins for this `EditText` so it doesn't take the full width of the dialog. How can I do this? (**I do not consider the option of inflating a custom `Layout` at this point**)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

if you don't want to inflate a custom Layout, 
Try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
final EditText email_input = new EditText(Login.this);
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(Login.this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

email_input.setHint("Email Address");
email_input.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

linearLayout.addView(email_input);
linearLayout.setPadding(60, 0, 60, 0);

dialog.setTitle("Forgot Password?");
dialog.setMessage("Enter Your Email Address");

dialog.setView(linearLayout);

dialog.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Some Code 
    }
});

dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can pass spacing parameter in `setView` method

```
alert.setView(view ,left_space , top_space , right_space , bottom_space);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!   I'd been trying the edittext padding, and layout parameters margins and neither were working.  This did it.

Comment: Its deprecated in newer api.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `setPadding (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)` method on your `EditText` before setting is as a view in the `AlertDialog`.

You can use negative padding to emulate margins in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of stuff, you will have to have a custom dialog box:

Here's how you can do this:

**Step 1: Create a CustomDialog.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;


    public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog{

    public Activity c;
    public Dialog d;
    public Button yes, no;

    public CustomDialogClass(Activity a) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = a;

    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);

    }

    }
```

**Step 2: Create a custom dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F3F3F4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2sp"
        android:background="#000000" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_dia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textColor="#00BFFF"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2sp"
        android:background="#000000" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F3F3F4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/navigationid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:text="@string/navigation"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" 
            android:textColor="#00BFFF"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2sp"
        android:background="#000000" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 3 : In you main activity in the onCreate(); just call this:**

```
final CustomDialogClass dialog = new CustomDialogClass(TutorialActivity.this);
        dialog.show();


           //This part is optional. Just to close the dialog after few seconds.
        final Timer time = new Timer();
        time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, 5000);
```

That's it..So simple .. :)

Comment: What is the timer for?

Comment: thanks for posting this awesome tutorial :) I could create a custom Dialog using like 90% less code, but my question was whether is it possible to set the margins in my scenario

Comment: I am sorry about that.. the timer was just for closing the dialog after few seconds. Yes..i agree with your comment..sorry about that..but yes, we can set the margin in the edit text if using a custom dialog. In the layout you use for the dialog.

Comment: @mike20132013 I guess I have to highlight the last statement in my question^^

Comment: I agree, great post anyway +1

Comment: Thanks for the plus.. but I think I don't deserve +1 for this post cause the answer was totally different from the question that was asked and I did misread the question.